# TypeError : Customer.update() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongodb-query

When I am executing other funcitons like find, add in database then they are running perfectly fine , but when I am updating the database entry then I am getting this error , I am using mongodb atlas, can someone help me how to solve this error. This is the github link of the code : [Github URL](https://github.com/Vinayak409/customer-cli)

This is the error which I am getting

[image]

I searched on internet but didn't find any solution which fixes my problem, so that's why I am asking a new question, a similar kind of question already being asked but that didn't work in my case

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Model.findOneAndUpdate()`.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

```js
// update customer
const updateCustomer = (_id, customer) => {
  Customer.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, customer).then((customer) => {
    console.info("Customer Updated");
    db.close();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your update query should look like this:

You may want to find by _id and update at the same time:

```
const customersData = {name: "test name", age: 24}

Customer.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, customersData)
```

Comment: You may want to find by _id and update at the same time:

`Customer.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, customersData)`

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm seeing in that library *Customer.update()* is not exposed as a standalone function but instead there's the identifier *updateCustomer* one can call...

```
const updateCustomer = (_id, customer) => {
  Customer.update(_id , customer).then((customer) => {
    console.info("Customer Updated");
    db.close();
  });
};
```

So use it directly like this...

```
updateCustomer(_id, customer);
```